# Why does it keep lib/modules locked?

Tags: java, windows, java-9

When I launch **any** third-party application, e.g. Notepad (but you could take anything else), from a Java 9 application and then exit the Java application:

```
import java.io.*;

public class LaunchNotepad {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"});
  }
}
```

the launched third party application keeps locking Java 9's `lib\modules` file. This makes it hard for our Java application with a private JRE to update itself, because the original directory (containing the JRE) can't be renamed. Here's a screenshot from ProcessExplorer (Sysinternals):

[image: Screenshot of ProcessExplorer showing the notepad process launched by Java 9]

This smells like a Java 9 bug (reported as [JDK-8194734](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8194734)), but **is there a work-around for launching an application on Windows without locking the `lib\modules` file**, e.g. by using an external (proxy) application that simply launches the passed parameter as an application?

Comment: It doesn't, you know. Notepad doesn't know Java from a hole in the ground.

Comment: The handle to the lib/modules file should not be inherited into child processes. If you are certain this is happening then please submit a bug.

Comment: I've already submitted a bug, but I don't know how long Oracle will need to fix it. I need a quick work-around, even if it is dirty. I'm a little bit frustrated that people put this question on hold because this does not solve any problem.

Comment: Can I ask why you need a Java progam to launch Notepad?

Comment: Voting to reopen this. @ThomasS. you could probably improve the quality of the question further by answering something like EJP's doubt. Also, would be great to update with the link to the bug for updates to community.

Comment: Good question, voted to reopen.

Comment: Did you try an explicit `System.exit(0)` after starting the other process?

Comment: Is `notepad.exe` just a placeholder or do you really want to open an editor? If yes `Desktop.getDesktop().edit(...)` is a working replacement that does not show the "modules handle bug".

Comment: @EJP It just is a sample. We launch another Java application (with a couple of parameters) that modifies the original Java application's installation (automatic update), but with Notepad it is also reproducible and it is available on each Windows installation, so easier to reproduce.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: of course, I did. It does not matter, because the Java application cleanly exited.

Comment: I don't have a link to the reported Java bug, but just the ID 9052156 (reported to Oracle).

Comment: Have you tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "start", "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"});`? That way, the `cmd` process that has the lock on lib/modules will exit immediately, leaving just Notepad running.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried that. `lib/modules` still is locked according to *ProcessExplorer*.

Comment: Just a suggestion: create a batch that runs the Java application. Have the Java app create a second batch, exit the app and have a `call second.cmd` in the first batch after the lines that launched the app. Dirty, indeed ... You can have something more elaborate and use `if`s and exit codes

Comment: What is `c:\temp\java-test` file?

Comment: `c:\temp\java-test` is the directory where the class file was stored and which I've added to the classpath.

Comment: The question has been updated with a screenshot showing Notepad.exe has inherited the handle to the jimage file. This is now tracked in the JDK JIRA here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194734

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I [fixed this bug](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/d2bea17edd96). Does this count as a workaround? :)

Otherwise, some workarounds are indeed possible.

**Workaround 1: Use awt.Desktop**

Scanning through the Java sources, I found that `awt.Desktop` can call `ShellExecute` for us.

Unfortunately, this method does not allow to pass commandline arguments. You can write a temporary batch file to disk and launch it as workaround.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Desktop;

public class LaunchNotepad {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File program = new File("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(program);
  }
}
```

**Workaround 2: Use PsExec as proxy**

[SysInternals PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) does not inherit files into processes started with it. Remember to use `-d` parameter, or PsExec itself will hold the file.

Using `cmd.exe` as proxy is not possible, because it always inherits handles.

**Workaround 3: Make your own proxy**

You will need to use one of two WINAPI's: [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) (specifying `bInheritHandles=FALSE`) or [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Oracle Java Support contract, you should go through the support channels to ask when a fix will be forthcoming.

**UPDATE** - Based on https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194734, the current answer is likely be "when Java 11 is released".  But Oracle may decide to backport the fix to Java 9 and 10.

If you are really desperate for a fix, then consider doing the following:

1. Download the OpenJDK source code and build your own JVM.
2. Figure out where the bug is.  You seem to know what it is, so it should not be hard to figure out where to look.
3. Develop a fix for the bug.
4. Contribute the fix to the OpenJDK project as a patch.

That will increase the likelihood of the problem being fixed sooner in the standard codebase and the distributions produced from it.  It will also give you a workaround for in-house testing and for customers who are willing to use your "fixed" JVM.

I mentioned one possible workaround that involved reworking your code which you rejected out of hand.  There are others too.  AFAIK there are no workarounds that don't involve work for you, one way or another.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  The fact that you don't like the answer does not make it a non-useful answer.  Indeed, when there is no easy answer, it is **clearly** useful to tell someone there is no easy answer so that they don't waste their time waiting for one.   And note that you have now been waiting for 2 weeks,

Comment: Your answer might be a work-around for a JDK developer, but not for an average Java developer without Windows API knowledge. Currently, our work-around is to continue using Java 8.

Comment: The other idea I suggested was suitable for an average Java developer, assuming that they are capable of developing a batch file ... or a native code launcher.   And if sticking with Java 8 is a work-around, then you had that before you asked the question :-)

Comment: And if sticking with Java 8 is a viable work-around, then you had that before you asked the question.  So what's with all of the beating on Oracle for not fixing the bug quickly enough for you?  Just be patient.

Comment: Realistically, this is probably the best possible answer.

Comment: The other answer totally substantiates your claim that it should be an easy fix :)